# What is the best approach for IPC between Java and C++ apps running on the same machine?

Tags: java, c++

I would like to implement a robust IPC solution between a single JVM applet and a C++ application running on the same machine. What is the best approach for doing so?

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @George: on some OSes TCP shall trigger security notification, even if it's only local TCP connection (for example on OS X).  This can be *very* nasty if it's an app to be shipped to many users because they may freak out seeing that your app: *"tries to access the network"* or whatever.

Answer (score 6):

sockets are about your best (only reasonable?) choice.  although if you are running an applet, you will have to deal with access permissions issues (signing the applet will probably solve these).

Answer (score 2):

Sockets as a transport protocol.

JSON as a message protocol, with optional length header or trailing zero if required.